# Injecting Ruby and puts into HTML

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a html.erb file where I have html code. I inserted this piece of ruby code

```
<li <%= puts "class='active'" %>>Link</li>
```

But when I run the code on rails server, `class="active"` is not rendered. Why is that and how do I fix it? Am I missing something basic and fundamental?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use puts. Use this:

```
<li <%= "class='active'" %>>Link</li>
```

`puts` prints a string to stdout and returns `nil`. That's why your class is not rendered.

### Update

To avoid escaping, prefix the string with `raw`

```
<li <%= raw "class='active'" %>>Link</li>
```

Or, if this is **really** what your code is (no simplification etc), you can just do

```
<li class='active'>Link</li>
```

Comment: In my page source, I'm returned with `<li class=&#x27;active&#x27; >`

Comment: Such silly mistakes from a greenhorn like me. Thanks for the answer and update.

Answer (score 3):

`puts` outputs a statement to STDOUT, or whatever console your server is running on. It won't get inserted into your view, it'll just be output by your server.

You don't need any statement at all for the ERB to be evaluated here. You can just do this:

```
<li <%= "class='active'" %>>Link</li>
```

Check out more details about the ERB templating language at [the Ruby on Rails view guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html).